# Failed to connect ... port 80: Timed out, R connection to a Bing API

Tags: r, connection, bing-api

I am using the function **geroute** from package {taRfix.geo}
, it extracts data from a Bing map API, here is a simple example

```
x <- georoute( c("3817 Spruce St, Philadelphia, PA 19104", 
               "9000 Rockville Pike, Bethesda, Maryland 20892"), 
               verbose=TRUE, returntype="time", 
               service="bing" )
```

the output I get is

```
Failed to connect to dev.virtualearth.net port 80: Timed out
```

I did check Microsofts documentation, the **georoute** function uses the API's listed link

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes

one of the other things I tried was **setInternet2()**  and **Setinternet2=TRUE** to no avail ...